# Jest encapsulate setup/teardown code into a function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to encapsulate some common setup/teardown code into a function like so:

```
export function testWithModalLifecycle() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const modalRootDom = document.createElement('div')
    modalRootDom.id = ModalRootDomId
    document.appendChild(modalRootDom)
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    const modalRootDom = document.getElementById(ModalRootDomId)
    if (modalRootDom) {
      modalRootDom.remove()
    }
  })
}
```

And the use this in tests where I need it:

```
describe('Modal', () => {
  testWithModalLifecycle()

  it('should render a modal', () => {
    //...
  })
})
```

But looks like my setup/teardown code is never called. Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible somehow?

Yes, it's possible.

Your function would just need to call `beforeEach` and `afterEach` synchronously within the function body, like you are doing, and the function would need to be called synchronously within the body of the `describe` callback, which you are also doing.

I set up a test and ran into an error with `document.appendChild`, but if that line is changed to `document.body.appendChild` then it worked fine:

util.js

```js
export const ModalRootDomId = 'myid';

export function testWithModalLifecycle() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const modalRootDom = document.createElement('div');
    modalRootDom.id = ModalRootDomId;
    document.body.appendChild(modalRootDom);  // <= append to the body
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    const modalRootDom = document.getElementById(ModalRootDomId);
    if (modalRootDom) {
      modalRootDom.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

code.test.js

```js
import { testWithModalLifecycle, ModalRootDomId } from './util';

describe('Modal', () => {
  testWithModalLifecycle()

  it('should render a modal', () => {
    const modalRootDom = document.getElementById(ModalRootDomId);
    expect(modalRootDom.outerHTML).toBe('<div id="myid"></div>');  // Success!
  })
})
```

Comment: Cheers, looks like these hooks were called after all, I was just doing dom manipulation wrong: `document.body.appendChild(modalRootDom)`